# Implement parallax effect on Header image from Content type field

Tags: javascript

I have a [Header image](http://landberg.at/nl/test-pagina) which i can upload *per node* from my Basic-page Content type. I want to implement [this parallax effect](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/), on my Header image section. But I need to add:

`<div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="/path/to/image.jpg"></div>`.

How do I add `data-image-src="/path/to/image.jpg"` to the wrapping `<div>`? It has to be dynamic and per node you must be able to attach a specific image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with a much easier way:

**1)** I installed the [Image URL Formatter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter)

**2)** now i am able in `Manage Display` > `Full content` > Field: `header_image` > under **Format** i can choose `Image URL`

**3)** Now in my `page.tpl.php` i can call my `header_image` URL like:

```
<figure>
   <div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-speed="-0.2" data-image-src="<?php print render($page['header_image']); ?>"></div>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you need to add that code? Into `field.tlp.php`, `node.tpl.php` or `page.tlp.php`? Is it D7 or D8?

If you need to extract `src` atribute (`/path/to/image.jpg`) from some `HTML` code (for example from the `node.tlp.php` field) then use [Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=extract%20src%20from%20html%20regular%20expressions). When you will have `src` then you can create desired `<div>` element in your template files.

As universal answer as detailed question was.

**Update:**

I found that you have attached your site so I suggest this:

1. Create block in Views for header image field

   - NID as Contextual Filter
   - Enable cache per page
   - Output header image field as src (only image url) - there is such [option in views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20664571/2195238) or use [this](http://drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) module
   - Override that field (`rewrite the output of this field`) with something as `<div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="[image_src]"></div>`
   - enable block in proper region only for "Basic-page" CT

Comment: thanks i try it know. But the first step 'NID as argument' how do i do this?

Comment: [Check this](http://dannyenglander.com/blog/using-views-contextual-filters-create-related-content-block-drupal-7). It's called like `Contextual Filter: Nid`. I'm sure you know what it is - it's very common in Views. I just used wrong term from D6.